# Generic Buffer with fancy swap function? How?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, traits

I came across this problem this morning:

I want to build a generic class **FrontBackBuffer** which I can use as the following (some examples).

**EDIT** Removed some confusing part!

```cpp
int bb=10;
int fb=3;
FrontBackBuffer< const int*, int & > buf(&fb, &bb);
buf.getBack() = 4; // change from 10 to 4
// buf.getFront() = 5; NO! is const!

buf.swap();
//NOW getFront() and getBack() should return  4 and 3!

FrontBackBuffer< int, const & int > buf(14, bb);
buf.getBack() = 5; // change from 4 to 5
// buf.getFront() = 5; NO! is const!

buf.swap();   
//NOW getFront() and getBack() should return  5 and 14!
```

It stores **two buffers**, should be of the **same underlying type** (see the static_assert).
These buffers can be of pointer type or reference type and also const or non const.
It has two functions `getFront()`and `getBack()`. These functions always return a reference to the underlying buffer, either const or non-const. That is why there are all sorts of `MyRefTypes` traits spezialization.

The class which works so far is as the following:

```cpp
template< typename TBufferTypeFront, typename TBufferTypeBack = TBufferTypeFront>
class FrontBackBuffer {

// If <const * int , int&> --> this result in is_same< int , int > 
// STATIC_ASSERT( std::is_same< RemoveModifiers<TBufferTypeFront>::type, typename RemoveModifiers<TBufferTypeFront>::type>::result )

public:

    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes {
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static Ref getRef(T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for Reference
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<T&> {
        typedef T & Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ref getRef(T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for const Reference
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T&> {
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ref getRef(const T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for const
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T> {
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ref getRef(const T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for pointers
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<T*> {
        typedef T* Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef T* const CRef;  //! note this is a pointer....
        static inline Ref getRef(T* v) {
            return *v;
        }
    };

//Specialization for const pointers
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T*> {
        typedef const T* Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T* const CRef; //! note this is a pointer....
        static inline Ref getRef(const T* v) {
            return *v;
        }
    };


    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Ref TBufferTypeFrontRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::CRef TBufferTypeFrontCRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Con TBufferTypeFrontCon;

    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Ref TBufferTypeBackRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::CRef TBufferTypeBackCRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Con TBufferTypeBackCon;

    explicit FrontBackBuffer(
        TBufferTypeFrontCon  front,
        TBufferTypeBackCon   back):
        m_Front(front),
        m_Back(back)
    {
             m_pBack = (void*)&m_Back;
             m_pFront = (void*)&m_Front;

    };


    ~FrontBackBuffer()
    {};

    TBufferTypeFrontRef getFront() {
        return MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::getRef(m_Front);
    }
    TBufferTypeBackRef getBack() {
        return MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack>::getRef(m_Back);
    }
    private:

    void swap(){
         void * temp = m_pFront;
         m_pFront = m_pBack;
         m_pBack = temp;
    }

    TBufferTypeFront * m_pFront;       ///< The pointer to front buffer
    TBufferTypeBack * m_pBack;         ///< The pointer to back buffer

    TBufferTypeFront m_Front;       ///< The front buffer
    TBufferTypeBack m_Back;         ///< The back buffer

};
```

The question is now (which I can not solve completely right):
How can I add a generic function `swap()` which swaps the buffers, but no copy should be made. I thought about two pointers `void * m_pFront`and `void *m_pBack`which I should use to do the job, and assigned correct (see constructor).

But how do I now write these getter functions is a mystery to me:

```
    TBufferTypeFrontRef getFront() {
        return MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::getRef(m_Front);
    }
    TBufferTypeBackRef getBack() {
        return MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack>::getRef(m_Back);
    }
```

At the end of the day it should just work :-)
Thanks for any help and trying to solve this puzzle :-)!

Comment: You can only swap `front` and `back` when they are the same or their pointers convertible to each other. Be aware that `swap` has a very specific meaning in the standard library and it is different from your meaning. Besides that, what you are trying to achieve doesn't look very useful to me, but I'm probably lacking context.

Comment: swap should do the same thing, internally it should switch the buffers, thas all, but an efficient one...

Comment: I too am very confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. I'm assuming that you know that you can't swap the buffers if they aren't of the same types? And if that's right, why don't you just store a variable about whether or not they are swapped or something.

Comment: Yea it is a bit confusing, but if one looks at the behaviour how the class should be used it should become clear, below is just an implmenetation trying to achieve this. It works with out the swap function... The thing is that this buffer can basically hold its own memory or refere to some other memory (pointers or references), for both front and back, And thats exactly the nice thing, you can use it very generic and it still does the thing! But the swap function is a hard problem. This class is only for template pleasure and maybe a bit overkill, but isnt it nice?

Comment: This feels like a wrong design. Plainly speaking, your class is not a buffer, rather a pointer/reference container. Perhaps it would be better to explain what task are you trying to accomplish and why can't you do it using a `std::pair` of pointers where swap is achieved by `std::swap(p.first, p.second)`? It is very efficient (moves 24B) and apparently also does what you want. Why are the types of buffers so important? Why is this worth writing a whole new container template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full answer!

The code works and the buffer is generic as hell :-) --> 
http://ideone.com/m3kFmo

And the swap function is also efficient and works as desired!

**Of course this class is only usefull when the underlying type is the same** like:
`FrontBackBuffer< int *, int &>` --> OK

`FrontBackBuffer< int *, const double &>` --> is ok, but swap function makes no sense then!

**Here the code! :-)**

```cpp
template< typename TBufferTypeFront, typename TBufferTypeBack = TBufferTypeFront>
class FrontBackBuffer {

    // If <const * int , int&> --> this result in is_same< int , int > 
    // STATIC_ASSERT( std::is_same< RemoveModifiers<TBufferTypeFront>::type, typename RemoveModifiers<TBufferTypeFront>::type>::result )

public:

    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes {
        typedef T Org;
        typedef T* Ptr;
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ptr getUnderlyingPtr(T& v) {
            return &v;
        }
        static Ref getRef(T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

    //Specialization for Reference
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<T&> {
        typedef T Org;
        typedef T* Ptr;
        typedef T & Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ptr getUnderlyingPtr(T& v) {
            return &v;
        }
        static inline Ref getRef(T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

    //Specialization for const Reference
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T&> {
        typedef T Org;
        typedef T* Ptr;
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ptr getUnderlyingPtr(const T& v) {
            return &const_cast<T&>(v);
        }
        static inline Ref getRef(const T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

    //Specialization for const
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T> {
        typedef T Org;
        typedef T* Ptr;
        typedef const T & Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T& CRef;
        static inline Ptr getUnderlyingPtr(const T& v) {
            return &const_cast<T&>(v);
        }
        static inline Ref getRef(const T& v) {
            return v;
        }
    };

    //Specialization for pointers
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<T*> {
        typedef T* Ptr;
        typedef T Org;
        typedef T* Con;
        typedef T& Ref;
        typedef T* const CRef;  //! note this is a pointer....
        static inline Ptr getUnderlyingPtr(T* v) {
            return v;
        }
        static inline Ref getRef(T* v) {
            return *v;
        }
    };

    //Specialization for const pointers
    template <typename T>
    struct MyRefTypes<const T*> {
        typedef T Org;
        typedef T* Ptr;
        typedef const T* Con;
        typedef const T& Ref;
        typedef const T* const CRef; //! note this is a pointer....
        static inline Ptr getUnderlyingPtr(const T* v) {
            return const_cast<T*>(v);
        }
        static inline Ref getRef(const T* v) {
            return *v;
        }
    };


    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Ref TBufferTypeFrontRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::CRef TBufferTypeFrontCRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Con TBufferTypeFrontCon;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Org TBufferTypeFrontOrg;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::Ptr TBufferTypeFrontPtr;

    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Ref TBufferTypeBackRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::CRef TBufferTypeBackCRef;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Con TBufferTypeBackCon;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Org TBufferTypeBackOrg;
    typedef typename MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack >::Ptr TBufferTypeBackPtr;

    explicit FrontBackBuffer(
                             TBufferTypeFrontCon  front,
                             TBufferTypeBackCon   back):
    m_Front(front),
    m_Back(back)
    {
        m_pBack = MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeBack>::getUnderlyingPtr(m_Back);
        m_pFront = MyRefTypes<TBufferTypeFront>::getUnderlyingPtr(m_Front);

    };


    ~FrontBackBuffer()
    {};

    TBufferTypeFrontRef getFront() {
        return *m_pFront;
    }
    TBufferTypeBackRef getBack() {
        return *m_pBack;
    }

    void swap(){
        TBufferTypeFrontPtr temp = m_pFront;
        m_pFront = m_pBack;
        m_pBack = temp;
    }

private:



    TBufferTypeFrontPtr m_pFront;       ///< The pointer to front buffer
    TBufferTypeBackPtr  m_pBack;         ///< The pointer to back buffer

    TBufferTypeFront m_Front;       ///< The front buffer
    TBufferTypeBack m_Back;         ///< The back buffer

};
```

We are able to use it in this way now:

```
int main() {
        int front=10;
    int back=3;
    FrontBackBuffer< const int*, int & > buf1(&front, back);
    buf1.getBack() = 4; // change from 3 to 4
    // buf.getFront() = 5; NO! is const!
    buf1.swap();
        std::cout << buf1.getFront() << buf1.getBack() << std::endl;
    //NOW getBack() and getFront() should return  4 and 10!

        front = 1;
        back= -1;
    FrontBackBuffer<int &, int > buf2(front, back);
    buf2.getBack() = 2; 
    buf2.getFront() = 3; 

    buf2.swap();   
    //NOW getBack() and getFront() should return  2 and 3!
    std::cout << buf2.getFront() << buf2.getBack() << std::endl;

        front = 1;
        back= -1;
    FrontBackBuffer<int, const int &> buf3(front, back);
    //buf3.getBack() = 2; // IS CONST!!
    buf3.getFront() = 3; 

    buf3.swap();   
    //NOW getBack() and getFront() should return  -1 and 3!
    std::cout << buf3.getFront() << buf3.getBack() << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I don't really understand why you need all the code you posted in order to accomplish the task you described, but I may be missing something. However considering you just want to swap two buffers of the same type in a generic but efficient way I would suggest the following:

```
template<typename BufferType>
class FrontBackBuffer
{
private:
    BufferType buffers[2];
    int _back,_front;
public:
/*
omitting copy constructors, operators etc for brevity
*/
    FrontBackBuffer()
        : _front(0), _back(1)
    {
         /*
           You can also start with front and back pointing to the same memory it is of no  importance if you remember to swap them once or if you just set the back buffer and never the front
         */
    }
    BufferType & getFront()
    {
        return buffers[_front];
    }
    BufferType & getBack()
    {
        return buffers[_back];
    }
    void swap()
    {
        _front = _back;
        _back = (_front + 1) % 2;
    }
};
```

And you can use it like this:

```
int intArray[] = {1,2,3,4};

FrontBackBuffer<int*> intPtrBuffers;
intPtrBuffers.getBack() = new int[4];
intPtrBuffers.getFront() = new int[4];

memcpy(intPtrBuffers.getBack(), intArray, sizeof(intArray));
intPtrBuffer.swap();
```

Comment: This is another way, but doesn not let me define the back and front individualy, what do you do if you would like to have the front buffer somewhere else :-)? not a member instance in your FrontBackBuffer :-)

Comment: @Gabriel Thank you for your comment. As I wrote - I probably don't understand your real needs. You wrote the buffers are of the same type so for me using two types: one for the back and one for the front may be very general but just makes unclear code. If you want to keep them somewhere else then you can always use pointers. I like to keep things simple. However your real needs may indeed require something more complicated. (As a side note: I would really like to know what kind of implementation requires a back and front  buffers of different types?)